# One-to-one with different classes in EF Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I'd like to follow [this blog](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-one-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx) explaining how to configure one-to-one relationship. Its idea is that one entity gets a property of the other's type while the other one gets a property of the former's type plus an ID to it to create a foreign key.

My issue is, though, that I want to brake out the contact part of two different classes like so. The class *SomeThing* is already refactored and works well with the class *Address*. However, I'm not sure how to deal with the class *SomeThingElse*.

```
public class SomeThing
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  //public string Street { get; set; }
  //public string City { get; set; }
  public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Street { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
  public Guid SomeThingId { get; set; }
  public SomeThing SomeThing { get; set; }  
}

public class SomeThingElse
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Street { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
  //public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried adding a specialized class for managing the address of *SomeThingElse* but then, it makes no sense to break it out. I considered adding the two fields below but rejected the idea as poor design for the DB.

```
public class Address
{
  ...
  public Guid SomeThingElseId { get; set; }
  public SomeThingElse SomeThingElse { get; set; }  
}
```

Preferably, this is a school book case for inheritance introducing a base class *Contactable* and skipping *Address* altogether. But I recall from before that inheritance and EF don't mix well and that there's a lot of oopsies and gotchas to be expected in such case.

Is there a reliable best-practice for doing that? I haven't found anything that felt trustable enough when I googled.

Comment: Little confused about what's being asked. So you want another 1:1 relationship between Address and SomethingElse?

Comment: I already have a relationship between *SomeThing* and *Address*. Now I want to also have a relationship between *SomethingElse* and *Address*. Both classes (*SomeThing* and *SomeThingElse*) have the contact information in them, which I intend to pull out to a separate class (i.e. *Address*). E.g. a student has an address but the school also has an address. Or, perhaps, an employee has a phone number but the company also has a phone number (where phone number can be a complex class containing all kinds of contact means as Skype, email and what not).

Comment: @DonkeyBanana I see you are putting wrong  navigation property in Address. It should be `public SomeThingElse SomeThingElse { get; set; } ` instead of `public SomeThing SomeThingElse { get; set; }`

Comment: @DonkeyBanana Between the `Address` and `SomeThingElse` which is Principal entity and which is dependent entity? Would you make it clear please?

Comment: To get you on the right track I suggest you read Bill Karwin's classic *Sql Anti Patterns*, in particular the part on polymorphic associations. That will help you make an educated decision on how to implement this.

Comment: Consider modeling Address as an OwnedType.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities

Comment: @TanvirArjel You're right. I corrected the typo. As for the question, I'm not sure what determines which is principal and which is dependent but I sense that it's *SomeThing* is the principal while *Address* is the dependent one. And correspondingly, *SomeThingElse* is the principal and *Address* is the dependent one.

Comment: @BrianOgden I'm trying to see how to resolve it using *Code First*, so scripting my DB isn't a feasible option. In SQL, that would be rather easy - I'd just throw in a column named *EntityId* and let the ID work both ways. But I'm curious on how to work it out from Fluent API direction.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft This was spot on great hint. Please post it as a reply because it **should** be accepted as the correct answer. That's **precisely** the use case many people have and it's always awkward to make it work the usual way. I love *OwnsOne(...)* method - it's new to the .NET Core, isn't it?

Comment: @DonkeyBanana as I had to sleep last night I could not answer then after getting your reply. Yes! I would have also suggested you to use owned entity type as **David Browne - Microsoft** did. By the way, I have through a details answer. Please check it. also a special thanks to **David Browne - Microsoft** :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As from the discussion in the comments, I am going into a details answer:

You can use **EF Core** newly introduced [Owned Entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)  type feature where `Address` is the `Owned Entity` type of `Something` and `SomethingElse` while `Something` and `SomethingElse` are the owners as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeThing>().OwnsOne(st => st.Address);
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeThingElse>().OwnsOne(st => st.Address);
```

By convention, EF Core will name the database columns for the properties of the owned entity type following the pattern *Navigation_OwnedEntityProperty*. Therefore the `Address` properties will appear in the `Something` and `SomethingElse` table with the names 'Address_Street' and 'Address_City'.

Now if you don't want owned entity type column name to be like *Navigation_OwnedEntityProperty* then you can give your custom column name as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeThing>().OwnsOne(st => st.Address,
     a =>
     {
          a.Property(p => p.Street).HasColumnName("Street");
          a.Property(p => p.City).HasColumnName("City");
     });

modelBuilder.Entity<SomeThingElse>().OwnsOne(ste => ste.Address,
     a =>
     {
          a.Property(p => p.Street).HasColumnName("Street");
          a.Property(p => p.City).HasColumnName("City");
     });
```

Moreover owned types can be stored in a separate table from the owner. In order to override the convention that maps an owned type to the same table as the owner, you can simply call `ToTable` and provide a different table name as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeThing>().OwnsOne(st => st.Address,
      a =>
      {
            a.ToTable("SomeThingAddress");
      });

 modelBuilder.Entity<SomeThingElse>().OwnsOne(ste => ste.Address,
      a =>
      {
          a.ToTable("SomeThingElseAddress");
      });
```

### Querying owned types

When querying the owner the owned types will be included by default. It is not necessary to use the Include method, even if the owned types are stored in a separate table.

### Limitations

Some of these limitations are fundamental to how owned entity types work, but some others are restrictions that we may be able to remove in future releases:

By-design restrictions:

- You cannot create a `DbSet<T>` for an owned type
- You cannot call `Entity<T>()` with an owned type on `ModelBuilder`

For more details: [EF Core Owned Entity Types Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#limitations)

Comment: This is the way to go.

Comment: Oh, this **owned entity** concept gave me an codegasm! I totally love when I get a comment referring me to some vague part of a book implicating that it's too complicated to resolve here. And then, somebody drops a one-liner and kills the issue. Awesome! I have a follow-up to that. Since the implementation of the concept is fairly new, the templates in VS don't suggest anything special for it when scaffolding. What would your suggestion (or guestimation) be in that regard? If I want to edit my entity, do I just throw in some extra fields for the data in the owned part?

Comment: @DonkeyBanana `If I want to edit my entity, do I just throw in some extra fields for the data in the owned part?`- Yes! Off course you can update the `owned type` with `owner` just updating `owned type` fields value like you will do for owner.